# Coverting raw PCM file to MP3 with LAME returns distorted audio

Tags: android, kotlin, mp3, pcm, lame

I have raw PCM files generated from a base64 string. [Here is the link to the API response that returns in.](https://pastebin.com/fwbezxMc).

I then create a PCM file from this string, after which I convert it to MP3 using the LAME library.

Here is the code that deals with the conversion:

```
    companion object {
  init {
      System.loadLibrary("mp3lame")
  }
  }


private external fun initEncoder(numChannels: Int, sampleRate: Int, bitRate: Int, mode: Int, quality: Int)
private external fun destroyEncoder()
private external fun encodeFile(sourcePath: String, targetPath: String): Int
val NUM_CHANNELS = 1
val SAMPLE_RATE = 16000
val BITRATE = 128
val MODE = 3
val QUALITY = 0

fun createAudioFromBase64AndGetPath(inputBase64: String, outputFileName: String) {
    initEncoder(NUM_CHANNELS, SAMPLE_RATE, BITRATE, MODE, QUALITY)

    val path: String = "newFile.wav"

    try {
        val decoded = Base64.decode(inputBase64, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        try {
            val fileRaw = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/$outputFileName.pcm")
            val fileEncoded = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/$outputFileName.mp3")


                val os = FileOutputStream(fileRaw, true)
                os.write(decoded)
                os.close()

            val result = encodeFile(fileRaw!!.absolutePath, fileEncoded!!.absolutePath)
            if (result == 0) {
                Log.d ("encoded to ", fileEncoded!!.name)
            }
            destroyEncoder()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e ("decode ", "first catch", e)
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.d ("decode ", "2nd catch", e)
    }
}
```

The audio comes out sounding like [this.](https://clyp.it/e0klimgx)

I've tried navigating the C library files that explain what the different variable options for **initEncoder** mean and I've fiddled around but nothing changes.

To try to troubleshoot this without the lag of compiling the app each time, I took the base64 string and converted it to a PCM file using an online converter (Motobit). I then used a very nifty (and free) converter for mac called XLD to test these conversions without having to compile the app each time to see if I could figure out what was going on, and if perhaps I was just using the wrong combination of variables for initEncoder.

The first thing I noticed was that I had to select the 'Open raw PCM (bin+cue)...' option in order to open the pcm filed downloaded from motobit.

Here is the selection window.
[image: The selection window]

The next piece of the puzzle, which seems to be the crucial piece, was that I was only able to convert the audio properly (without the noise) when selecting "Little" in the Endian box. The problem is that back in my app, I am unable to find out how or if I even can access and change this property in the LAME library.

For clarity, I'm using the wrapper from here: https://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get desperate, you can always switch the endianness yourself:

```
for (i in decoded.indices step 2)
{
    val swap = decoded[i]
    decoded[i] = decoded[i + 1]
    decoded[i + 1] = swap
}
```

...since `Base64.decode()` returns a byte array, and I'm assuming you're using 16-bit audio.

I couldn't find the `initEncoder()` docs, myself.

Comment: Amazing, it works! What makes you regard this a desperate measure though? Its nice and simple. If I understand correctly, is this swapping every 2 bytes around? If so, why is this a thing?

Comment: @Glenncito It's not bad or anything, it's just inelegant, if it turns out your audio library had a way to do it for you. I don't know if that's the case or not. Glad it worked!